# Greensock toggle animation not working on click

Tags: jquery, gsap

```
var MenuButton= $('.menu-button');

var clicked = false;
click.click(function() {

   if(clicked){
        TweenMax.to(menu-button, 1, {left: '100%', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
   }else{
        TweenMax.to(menu-button, 1, {left: '0%', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
   }
   clicked = !clicked;
});
```

I have a menu button (div class). When clicked the button should animate to the left. I have no idea what im doing wrong. I also tried replacing menu-button with MenuButton. Im more used to jquery so im abit confused of how toggling works with Greensock.

Where is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare click object which is able to use click method? If not, replace it by your MenuButton variable declared before (which already is jQuery object). If you want to animate just single button, use "this" instead. Code below should work:

```
var MenuButton= $('.menu-button');
var clicked = false;
MenuButton.click(function() {
    if(clicked){
        TweenMax.to(this, 1, {left: '100%', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
   }else{
        TweenMax.to(this, 1, {left: '0%', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
   }
   clicked = !clicked;
});
```